# Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n d\mu = \int f d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $(f_n)$ is a sequence of bounded measurable functions on $X$, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $X$. Prove that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_Xf_n d\mu = \int_X f d\mu$$

$$\int_X|f_n-f|d\mu\le\mu(X)\sup_{x\in X}\{|f_n-f|\}$$

Using uniform convergence and fact that $\mu (X)$ is finite, we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_X|f_n-f|d\mu\le 0$$

That's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f$ must be integrable, which is proved via:

$$\int_X|f|d\mu\leq \int_X|f-f_n|d\mu+\int_X|f_n|d\mu\leq A\mu(X)+B\mu(X)<\infty,$$

(for large enough $n$).

Comment: $\int_X|f|d\mu < \infty,$ does not paly any role in argument !

Comment: @Ashkan: Whoops misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to show that $f$ is measurable (or at least you point it out), otherwise  $ \int_X|f_n-f|d\mu$ is not well-defined, Then the rest of your proof is indeed correct.

Note that : you don't need to show that  $\int_X|f|d\mu < \infty,$  at all. your proof is correct without it. Even your proof is correct without the assumption of boundedness of $f_n$'s ! in this case you may have  $\int_X|f|d\mu =+ \infty,$ which confirms $\int_X|f|d\mu < \infty,$ is out of scoop!